# Find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{k} x^{k^2}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification, power-series

For my homework I have to find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{k} x^{k^2}$, I found :

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \left|\frac{2^{k+1}x^{\left(k+1 \right)^2}}{2^k x^{k^2}}\right| = \left|\frac{2x^{k^2+2k+1}}{x^{k^2}}\right| = \left| 2x^{2k+1} \right| = 2 \cdot \lim_{k\to\infty} \left| x^{2k+1} \right| = 2 \cdot \left| x^{\infty} \right| $$

Thus the power serie converges only when $x=0$.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: What about $|x|<1$?

Comment: Applying the Cauchy test is simpler  in my opinion $(2^k|x|^{k^2})^{1/k}=2|x|^k.$

Answer (score 4):

No, it is incorrect.

At $x=-1$ and $x=1$, the series is divergent.

For $\forall x\in (-1,1)$,
$$2 \lim_{k\to \infty} |x^{2k+1}|=0<1$$
So the convergent radius is $1$.